# Word for "the guiding words that teacher says during training to help participants perform the exercise"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For example, in Taiji, Yoga, etc., in a training class, during the training the teacher might say a series of words as guides for what the participants should do, such as "lift this body part up" "move this body part in this way" "close your eyes" etc.

What's the word in English for this kind of "guiding words" during training spoken by the teacher to help guide the participants during the training? Is there a specific word for it?

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Please update the post with what research you performed, what words you found that were close, and why those words did not suffice.

Comment: Syntactically, they're ***imperatives*** (with implied subject ***you***).

Comment: In language teaching this methodology is called _Total Physical Response_ (TPR): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_physical_response .  The instructor issues commands such as: _Put your left hand on your head. Point to the clock. Walk to the door_. So a generic term for such instructions is _command_.

Comment: Could we turn that round and say a generic term for such commands is instructions, however nit-picky it sounds at first?

For a military drill instructor or a martinet of a dance choreographer, orchestral conductor or the like, *command* might be appropriate.

Otherwise doesn't even *instruction* sound quite strict; dictatorial, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the term: Instructions

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Here, we prefer answers with more content; please provide more than just a word suggestion. Try reading [How To Answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Provide definitions for your suggested word, some formatting to aid in reading the answer, and a source for your word/definition. Sometimes it's also nice to add some reasoning behind why you feel the word fits well but that is not required. Also, it's bad practice to answer questions where the OP has shown zero research.